# netstat command local address format

Tags: netstat

I have below `netstat -ao` result.

```
Proto  Local Address
TCP    0.0.0.0:22
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306
TCP    165.120.144.11:139
TCP    [::]:80
```

In this result what does IP `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`, `165.120.144.11` and `[::]` indicates?

Comment: See this [too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882/how-do-i-interpret-netstat-a-output)

Comment: I know :: is IPv6 type of IP address and 127.0.0.1 is localhost or your own computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is the wildcard address - which means your machine is listening on port `22` (SSH) on all interfaces/IP addresses that it can see.

`[::]` is another way to represent this for IPv6.

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address; which means your machine is listening on port `3306` (MySQL) on localhost only.

`165.20.144.11` is most likely your external/internet facing IP address.